# Ubuntu Core 18: serial-getty@.service keeps timing out, delaying initial boot

Tags: boot, snap, tty, ubuntu-core

I have a custom ARM device that I am trying to enable Core 18 on. serial-getty@ttymxc1.service gets into a failure loop (whereupon it times out starting the service for 90 seconds, then tries to start up 8 more times like this, until it gives up) that delays the rest of the boot. It does eventually fail, and finishes booting the system so that I can SSH in, but when it gets in this state, the serial interface behaves... strangely. The initial config menu seems to keep resetting over and over.

On the second boot, the service seems to start fine and the serial console behaves normally. My current working theory is that perhaps something is not configured in time to start the serial-getty@.service.

Has anyone ever encountered this before? How do I fix it in the image? Push comes to shove, should I submit a bug report?

EDIT: It would probably be acceptable to disable the service, though on Core, I'm not sure how that'd be done at install time. Perhaps an install hook?

Comment: On an already-installed Core system, you login normally (using ssh) and `sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttymxc1.service` so it simply doesn't run at boot. On a custom install, depends upon if you need a serial login at all; production devices should not be using a custom login instead of millions of users trying to login using your personal Ubuntu One ssh key.

Comment: That would probably be an acceptable solution. How would I do this? An install hook? 
The issue only happens on initial install. The device is already configured with a default login and password via a configure hook.

Comment: If nobody's going to use the serial port, then sure -- a disabling install hook seems appropriate. My thought: A default install of Core in a VM or on a Pi doesn't time out the same way. This leads me to suspect that you perhaps don't have a working serial port connection anyway. If you DO have a working serial port connection, then seems like you have discovered a bug that should be investigated instead.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is actually [sort of a known issue already](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-service-delays-startup-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-4-15-0-24) and can be solved simply by updating your kernel. I updated from `4.14` to `4.19` and it works now.